Does $y\in[0,\:1]\implies y\in f((-1,\:1])$?
Suppose that $f(x)=x^2$. Find $f((-1,\:1])$.
$y\in f((-1,\:1])$ iff $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in(-1\:1]$
iff $y=x^2$ for some $x\in(-1\:1]$
iff $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $-1<x≤1$
iff $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $-1<x<0$ or $0≤x≤1$
iff $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $0<x^2<1$ or $0≤x^2≤1$
iff $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $0≤x^2≤1$
iff $y=x^2$ and $0≤y≤1$.
Hence $f((-1\:1])=[0,\:1]$.
The forward direction appears valid, but I’m not entirely sure about the converse statements. It seems line $5$ does not imply line $4$.

I think it is the line $0<x^2< 1$ or $0 \le x^2 \le 1 \iff -1<x<0$ or $0\le x \le 1$ that (although true) needs some verification and explaining and clarifying (which can be done).

I'd suggest proving that if $0\le a\le b$ then $f([a,b])=[a^2,b^2]$ (by citing for every $k\in [a^2,b^2]$ there is a unique $\sqrt{k}\ge 0$ and $a=\sqrt{a^2} \le \sqrt k \le \sqrt{b^2}=b$ and so $[a^2,b^2]\subset f([a,b])$ and for ever $w\in[a,b]$ then $a^2\le w^2\le b^2$ so $f([a,b])\subset[a^2,b^2]$). Then do the same for $m<n<0$ then $f((n,m))=[m^2,n^2]$.  Thus $f((-1,1])=f((-1,0))\cup f([0,1]) = (0,1)\cup[0,1]=[0,1]$.

One problem you might have with if and only if is that $0\le y^2 \le 1 \not \iff -1< y\le 1$.  Instead it is $0\le y^2 \le 1 \iff -1 \le y \le 1$.  This is actually not a problem as $f((-1,1]) = f([-1,1])$  (In fact $f((-1,1]) = f([0,1)) = f([-1,-\frac 12)\cup[\frac 14,\frac 78))=....$ almost any crazy set where either the negative of positive [but not necessarily both] of all $[0,1]$ is included)

It's perhaps easier to prove each inclusion separately. To show that $[0,1]\subseteq f((-1,1]$, let $y\in[0,1]$. Then there exists $x\in(-1,1]$ such that $f(x)=x^2=y$ since we can let $x=\sqrt{y}$. Therefore, $y\in f((-1,1])$.


$y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $−1<x<0$ or $0≤x≤1$ iff $y=x^2$
for some $x$ such that $0<x^2<1$ or $0≤x^2≤1$

... At this point you need to explain why this is true.  In general $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $a < x < b \le 0$ or $0 \le m \le n$ if and only if $b^2 < x^2 < a^2$ or $m^2 < x^2 < n^2$ is certainly NOT true because the latter would allow for the possibility that $|b| < x < |a|$ or that $-n \le x \le -m$.
In this case it is fine as $y = (-1)^2 \iff y=(1)^2$ so if $y$ is a square of $-1$ which is NEITHER in $(-1,0)$ NOR in $[0,1]$, $y$ can still be, and is a square of something else, namely of $1$, that is in one or the other.
I don't immediately see any way to do a single if and only if statement (combining if and only if with or conditions is... tenuous).
I'd do ifs and only ifs in stages at this point.
$\implies$: If $y =x^2$ for some $x$ such that $-1<x < 0$ or $0\le x \le 1$ then $y=x^2$ for some $x^2$ so that $0< x^2< 1$ or $0 \le x^2 \le 1$.
$\Leftarrow$:  If $y=x^2$ for some $x$ such that $0< x^2 < 1$ or $0\le x^2 \le 1$ then $y=x^2$ for some $x$ so that either ($0<x < 1$ or $-1< x<0$) or ($0\le x \le 1$ or $-1 \le x \le 0$). The can be restated as $x=-1$ or $-1 < x < 0$ or $0\le x \le 1$.  If $x=-1$ then $y^2 =(-1)^2 =(1)^2$ so the case that $y = x^2;x=-1$ is included in the case that $y=x^2$ for some $x: 0\le x \le -1$.  So if $y=x^2$ for some $x$ where $0< x^2 < 1$ or $0 \le x^2 \le 1$ then $y=x^2$ for some $x$ were $-1<x<0$ and $0\le x \le 1$.
So the iff between the statement holds.
But it is probably easy to not try to do it clause by clause but to attack the clauses as needed.  It'd also probably be easier to do this as a set rather than an individual $y$.
To prove $f((-1,1]) = [0,1]$ you prove
1.$f((-1,1]) \subset [0,1]$ and
2. $[0,1]\subset f((-1,1])$.
What you did was pretty much prove 1) but gets messy when we try to have it prove 2) at the same time.
Proof of 1:
$y \in f((-1,1]\iff y=x^2$ for $x\in (-1,1]\iff y=x^2$ for $x: -1<x < 0$ or $0\le x \le 1\implies y=x^2$ where $0< x^2 < 1$ or $0\le x^2 \le 1\iff y=x^2$ where $0\le x^2 < 1\iff 0\le y\le 1\iff y \in [0,1]$.
So .$f((-1,1]) \subset [0,1]$
Note we didn't need the $\Leftarrow$ in the one spot it was tricky.
And Proof of 2:
If $y\in [0,1]$ then $y \ge 0$ so $\sqrt y$ exists, and as $y \le 1$ so $0\le \sqrt{y} \le 1$.  So $\sqrt{y} \in [0,1] \subset (-1,1]$ and $y = \sqrt{y}^2 = f(\sqrt y)$ so $y \in f((-1,1])$ so
$[0,1]\subset f((-1,1])$
Note:  You never even had to touch the negative terms at all! This direction we are proving something stronger so we don't need to do all the weak cases (whereas in the first direction we were only going in one direction we didn't need to the weak case in the other direction.)
...
Might be worth noting $f([0,1]) = f((-1,1]) = f([-1,0]) = f([-1,-\frac 12]\cup [0,\frac 12))=....$ etc.
======
It occurs to me:
Consider if you had been asked to prove the following (true) statement:
Let $A=\{$all rational numbers $q$ where $0\le q \le 1\}$ and
$B = \{$all irrational numbers $w$ where $-1 < w < 0\}$ and
$C = A\cup B$.
Prove $f(C) = [0,1]$.
Trying to prove it as you attempt by single lines that an complete and total ("if and only if") would be damned near impossible (maybe not actually impossible but danged near).
Easy to do inclusion cases.
If $x\in C$ then $0\le |x| \le 1$.  Therefore $0 \le x^2 \le 1$ so $f(x)\in [0,1]$ and $f(C)\subset [0,1]$.
If $w \in [0,1]$ then $0 \le \sqrt w \le 1$.  If $\sqrt w\in \mathbb Q$ then $\sqrt{w} \in A\subset C$ so $w = \sqrt{w}^2=f(\sqrt w)\in f(C)$.
If $\sqrt w\not \in \mathbb Q$ then $-1< -\sqrt w < 0$ and $-\sqrt w \in B\subset C$ so $w=(-\sqrt w)^2 =f(-\sqrt w) \in f(C)$.
So either way $w \in f(C)$ and $[0,1] \subset f(C)$.
So $f(C) = [0,1]$
Do you see why I am reluctant to attempt stick absolute line by line if and only ifs.

Nice! Yes, I think proving the inclusions separately is the best approach.

Thanks for looking at this!
